# Access to script at has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, cdn, import-maps

I have an issue on all my servers and localhost by getting CORS error when getting js files from CDN.

It occurs today and nothing was changed in the codebase before. Yesterday everything works fine.

The problem exists in some of the networks and doesn't exists on other networks. I have rails 7 and importmaps, I use default CDN server here.

I try any solutions I've found but nothing happens. It's related to many files, not only lodash.

Additionally when I try to download locally, I have an 404 error that file doesn't exists.

I attach in the image all errors.

I will be happy for any help - it blocks all the sites for users :(

```
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/8c2fb8ba.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
uniq.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/8c2fb8ba.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_arrayMap.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
has.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_arrayMap.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/c35a08c6.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
camelCase.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/c35a08c6.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/76df6b91.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
camelCase.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/76df6b91.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/a3efd896.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
camelCase.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/a3efd896.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/b34f4de0.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
repeat.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/b34f4de0.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/337a6d53.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/337a6d53.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/1e5a3e69.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/1e5a3e69.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_baseIteratee.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_baseIteratee.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/3b1d2d22.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/3b1d2d22.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/812d2a38.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/812d2a38.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_baseProperty.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_baseProperty.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_getTag.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_getTag.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/d3f3cf39.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
sortBy.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lodash@4.17.21/_/d3f3cf39.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://ga.jspm.io/npm:storage2@0.1.2/lib/client.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
index.js:1     GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:storage2@0.1.2/lib/client.js net::ERR_FAILED 503
```

[image]

I tried download library locally (doesn't load), clear cache, use rack-cors - nothing has helped.